# How to avoid hanging of System.Media.SoundPlayer if underlying device is removed?

Tags: c#, windows, soundplayer

I am playing sounds with `System.Media.SoundPlayer`. Unfortunately the C# application tends to hang forever if the underlying sound device is removed during the play.

I could detect the removal of the device and stop the playback. But this seems to be (already) too late.

There is no exception or so, any chance to avoid the "crash" of the C# application?

Comment: Have you tried to borrow a ThreadPool Thread to execute the SoundPlayer, then use an async method, with a timeout set, to query the status when you receive, e.g., a `WM_DEVICECHANGE` message?

Comment: Nice idea to run it in a thread to avoid the hanging, I only need to "Kill" the thread.

Comment: No need to. I meant a Task. You can pass a CancellationToken to [WaitAsync()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.waitasync), assuming you're targeting .NET 7+

Comment: Great idea! Will try and see if this solves the issue.

Comment: You can add this as an answer, it seems to work. Thanks for the idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Jimi pointed out, running the `SoundPlayer` in a `Task` helps. Credits to him.

```
CancellationToken ct = _cancelPlaySource.Token;
_playTask = Task.Run(() =>
{
    Thread.CurrentThread.Name = "Play testsound for SAMS";
    SoundPlayer soundPlayer = new(mediaFilePath);
    soundPlayer.Play();

    // we need some time to allow to play the music
    // PlaySync cannot be stopped from outside
    const int SleepMs = 500;
    int playTimeMs = durationMs + SleepMs; // max time
    for (int i = 0; i < (playTimeMs / SleepMs) && !ct.IsCancellationRequested; i++)
    {
        if (i * SleepMs > durationMs) break;
        Thread.Sleep(SleepMs);
    }
    soundPlayer.Stop();
}, ct);
```